# "Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain \ specifications involving the variables", leading to unexpected results

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

While trying to maximize the function `fun[x_, a_,  b_]`, over parameters $a$ and $b$, and plotting the resulting maxima with respect to $x$,  I encountered the error "Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain 
specifications involving the variables", leading to unexpected plot

```
    fun[x_, a_, 
   b_] = -(b/2 + 
       1/48 a (22 - 5 Cos[2 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] - 
          3 Cos[6 x])) (((4 a + 10 a Cos[2 x] - 4 a Cos[4 x] + 
           6 a Cos[6 x] + 
           Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + 
               27 a^2 Cos[4 x] - 16 b^2 Cos[4 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 
               38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 
               5 a^2 Cos[12 x])) Log[
          1/96 (48 a + 48 b - 
             Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 
                 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + (27 a^2 - 16 b^2) Cos[4 x] - 
                 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 
                 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 5 a^2 Cos[12 x]))])/(2 Sqrt[
         2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + 
            27 a^2 Cos[4 x] - 16 b^2 Cos[4 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 
            38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 
            5 a^2 Cos[12 x])) + ((-4 a - 10 a Cos[2 x] + 
           4 a Cos[4 x] - 6 a Cos[6 x] + 
           Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + 
               27 a^2 Cos[4 x] - 16 b^2 Cos[4 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 
               38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 
               5 a^2 Cos[12 x])) Log[
          
          1/96 (48 a + 48 b + 
             Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 
                 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + (27 a^2 - 16 b^2) Cos[4 x] - 
                 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 
                 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 5 a^2 Cos[12 x]))])/(2 Sqrt[
         2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + 
            27 a^2 Cos[4 x] - 16 b^2 Cos[4 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 
            38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 
            5 a^2 Cos[12 x]))) - (b/2 + 
      1/48 a (26 + 5 Cos[2 x] - 2 Cos[4 x] + 
         3 Cos[6 x])) (((-4 a - 10 a Cos[2 x] + 4 a Cos[4 x] - 
           6 a Cos[6 x] + 
           Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + 
               27 a^2 Cos[4 x] - 16 b^2 Cos[4 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 
               38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 
               5 a^2 Cos[12 x])) Log[
          1/96 (48 a + 48 b - 
             Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 
                 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + (27 a^2 - 16 b^2) Cos[4 x] - 
                 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 
                 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 5 a^2 Cos[12 x]))])/(2 Sqrt[
         2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + 
            27 a^2 Cos[4 x] - 16 b^2 Cos[4 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 
            38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 
            5 a^2 Cos[12 x])) + ((4 a + 10 a Cos[2 x] - 
           4 a Cos[4 x] + 6 a Cos[6 x] + 
           Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + 
               27 a^2 Cos[4 x] - 16 b^2 Cos[4 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 
               38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 
               5 a^2 Cos[12 x])) Log[
          1/96 (48 a + 48 b + 
             Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 
                 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + (27 a^2 - 16 b^2) Cos[4 x] - 
                 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 
                 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 5 a^2 Cos[12 x]))])/(2 Sqrt[
         2] \[Sqrt](58 a^2 + 12 b^2 + 8 a^2 Cos[2 x] + 
            27 a^2 Cos[4 x] - 16 b^2 Cos[4 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[6 x] + 
            38 a^2 Cos[8 x] + 4 b^2 Cos[8 x] - 4 a^2 Cos[10 x] + 
            5 a^2 Cos[12 x]))) + 
   a (1/48 (22 - 5 Cos[2 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] - 
         3 Cos[6 x]) (((4 + 10 Cos[2 x] - 4 Cos[4 x] + 6 Cos[6 x] + 
              Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                  4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                  5 Cos[12 x])) Log[
             1/96 (48 - 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x]))])/(2 Sqrt[
            2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 4 Cos[6 x] + 
               38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 5 Cos[12 x])) + ((-4 - 
              10 Cos[2 x] + 4 Cos[4 x] - 6 Cos[6 x] + 
              Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                  4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                  5 Cos[12 x])) Log[
             1/96 (48 + 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x]))])/(2 Sqrt[
            2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 4 Cos[6 x] + 
               38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 5 Cos[12 x]))) + 
      1/48 (26 + 5 Cos[2 x] - 2 Cos[4 x] + 
         3 Cos[6 x]) (((-4 - 10 Cos[2 x] + 4 Cos[4 x] - 6 Cos[6 x] + 
              Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                  4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                  5 Cos[12 x])) Log[
             1/96 (48 - 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x]))])/(2 Sqrt[
            2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 4 Cos[6 x] + 
               38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 5 Cos[12 x])) + ((4 + 
              10 Cos[2 x] - 4 Cos[4 x] + 6 Cos[6 x] + 
              Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                  4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                  5 Cos[12 x])) Log[
             1/96 (48 + 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x]))])/(2 Sqrt[
            2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 4 Cos[6 x] + 
               38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 5 Cos[12 x]))) - 
      1/3 I Cos[
        x] (1 + 2 Cos[
           2 x]) (-((I (-4 - 10 Cos[2 x] + 4 Cos[4 x] - 6 Cos[6 x] + 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x])) (4 + 10 Cos[2 x] - 4 Cos[4 x] + 
                6 Cos[6 x] + 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x])) Csc[x]^3 Log[
               1/96 (48 - 
                  Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x]))] Sec[x])/(64 Sqrt[
              2] (1 + 
                2 Cos[2 x]) \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                 4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                 5 Cos[12 x]))) + (I (-4 - 10 Cos[2 x] + 4 Cos[4 x] - 
              6 Cos[6 x] + 
              Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                  4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                  5 Cos[12 x])) (4 + 10 Cos[2 x] - 4 Cos[4 x] + 
              6 Cos[6 x] + 
              Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                  4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                  5 Cos[12 x])) Csc[x]^3 Log[
             1/96 (48 + 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x]))] Sec[x])/(64 Sqrt[
            2] (1 + 
              2 Cos[2 x]) \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
               4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
               5 Cos[12 x]))) Sin[x]^3 + 
      1/3 I Cos[x] (1 + 2 Cos[2 x]) Sin[
        x]^3 ((8 I Sqrt[2]
             Cos[x] (1 + 2 Cos[2 x]) Log[
             1/96 (48 - 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x]))] Sin[
             x]^3)/(\[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
              4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
              5 Cos[12 x])) - (8 I Sqrt[2]
             Cos[x] (1 + 2 Cos[2 x]) Log[
             1/96 (48 + 
                Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
                    4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
                    5 Cos[12 x]))] Sin[
             x]^3)/(\[Sqrt](58 + 8 Cos[2 x] + 27 Cos[4 x] - 
              4 Cos[6 x] + 38 Cos[8 x] - 4 Cos[10 x] + 
              5 Cos[12 x])))) + 
   b (1/2 (1/2 Log[1/24 (13 - Cos[4 x])] + 
         1/2 Log[1/24 (11 + Cos[4 x])]) + 
      1/2 (1/2 Log[
           1/24 (13 - Cos[4 x])] - ((Csc[2 x]^2 - 
            Cos[4 x] Csc[2 x]^2) Log[1/24 (11 + Cos[4 x])])/(
         2 (-Csc[2 x]^2 + Cos[4 x] Csc[2 x]^2))) - 
      1/12 (1/4 (-Csc[2 x]^2 + Cos[4 x] Csc[2 x]^2) Log[
           1/24 (13 - Cos[4 x])] + 
         1/4 (Csc[2 x]^2 - Cos[4 x] Csc[2 x]^2) Log[
           1/24 (11 + Cos[4 x])]) Sin[2 x]^2 - 
      1/12 (Log[1/24 (13 - Cos[4 x])]/(-Csc[2 x]^2 + 
          Cos[4 x] Csc[2 x]^2) - 
         Log[1/24 (11 + Cos[4 x])]/(-Csc[2 x]^2 + 
          Cos[4 x] Csc[2 x]^2)) Sin[2 x]^2);

fun[x_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaxValue[{fun[x, a, b], {0 <= a < 1, 0 <= b < 1, a + b == 1}}, {a, 
   b}]
maxfun = fun /@ Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 0.05];
lpS3 = ListLinePlot[maxfun, DataRange -> {0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 6]
```

Irrelevant text: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Comment: Why the _Irrelevant text:..._ ?

Comment: Because it was saying, something like, your question contains mostly the code. So I put some random text!

Answer (score 2):

Use the constraints to simplify the objective function. **This is slow.**

```
fun2[x_, a_, b_] = 
  fun[x, a, b] //
   Simplify[#, {0 <= a < 1, 0 <= b < 1, a + b == 1}] &;

LeafCount /@ {fun[x, a, b], fun2[x, a, b]}

(* {3175, 2278} *)
```

Due to the numerical complexity of the function, track and control the precision by using arbitrary-precision (i.e., specify the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)) rather than machine precision.

```
fun[x_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[
  {fun2[x, a, b], 0 <= a < 1, 0 <= b < 1, a + b == 1}, {a, b},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

maxfun = fun /@ Range[0.05, 2 π, 0.05];

lpS3 = ListLinePlot[maxfun, DataRange -> {0, 2 π}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 6]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Akku14 the dependence on `b` can be eliminated since `a + b == 1`. This improves the accuracy of the maximization and provides a smoother curve.

```
fun3[x_, a_] = 
  fun[x, a, b] /. b -> 1 - a // Simplify[#, 0 <= a < 1 && 0 <= x < 2 Pi] &;

LeafCount /@ {fun[x, a, b], fun3[x, a]}

(* {3175, 2290} *)

mfun[x_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[{fun3[x, a], {0 < a < 1}}, a,
   WorkingPrecision -> 15];

maxfun = {#, mfun[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2 π, 0.05`20];

lpS3 = ListLinePlot[maxfun, InterpolationOrder -> 6, PlotRange -> {0, .035}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Bob Hanlon, making use of the condition a+b==1 gives better results.  `fun3[x_, a_] = 
  fun[x, a, b] /. b -> 1 - a // 
   Simplify[#, 0 < a < 1 && 0 < x < 2 Pi] &; `  .  and   `mfun[x_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[{fun3[x, a], {0 < a < 1}}, a];
maxfun = {#, mfun[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 0.05];
lpS3 = ListLinePlot[maxfun, InterpolationOrder -> 6, 
  PlotRange -> {0, .035}] ` .

Comment: Have a nice plot  `Plot3D[fun3[x, a], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {a, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 60] ` .

Comment: @Akku14 - very good.